# Polars, compute new column by cross referencing two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

First of all I have to say this is my first time using any DataFrame module.

I have need to process FEM simulation results that I have loaded into polars dataframe, which produce two DataFrames:

```
nodes_df = pl.DataFrame(
   {"node":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
       "x":[4.5,-4.6, 3.8,-3.8, 2.1,-9.3, 1.5,-6.7, 0.0, 3.6],
       "y":[9.8,-9.9, 8.2,-8.3, 4.6,-2.0, 1.4,-6.1, 0.0, 1.0],
       "z":[0.0,0.0,8.8,8.8,1.2,1.2,5.5,5.5,5.5,0.0,]})

elements = [1, 2, 3]
elements_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "element": elements,
        "N_1": [1, 1, 1],
        "N_2": [2, 2, 2],
        "N_3": [3, 3, 3],
        "N_4": [4, 4, 4],
        "N_5": [5, 5, 5],
        "N_6": [6, 6, 6],
        "N_7": [7, 7, 7],
        "N_8": [8, 8, 8],
        "N_9": [9, 9, 9],
        "N_10": [10, 10, 10],
    }
)
```

This data represent the values of a 10 node elements C3D10 like this:

[image: C3D10 Abaqus element]

the `elements_df`contains the definition for all elements, where the columns `N_{x}` are de ids of it's nodes (the node order is important), so each element always have 10 different nodes. The `nodes_df` can have more columns with other simulation results that I will process latter. The Idea is pass that results stored in the `nodes_df` to the element centroid.

The example have 10 (fake) nodes, and 3 (equals fake) elements, this are just sample data every row will be different. Where `nodes_df` has an `"node"` column to represent the node id, and `x,y,z` are the node coordinates. The `elements_df` has an "element" column for the id, and `N_<int[1:n]>` columns for it's nodes ids. First I´dont know if this schema is better or worst than having a single column with a list of nodes in one column, thinking on performance and easy of use of the dataframe, I have no problen to change the schema.

But I need to make cross reference of both dataframes to make several computations of my results. To start I need to compute the the element centroid.

As I'm new with dataframe I did this to clarify my point, but I know that this is the worst DataFrame code that anyone can write:

```
def coords(nodes: list):
    # get nodes coordinates for a node list
    return (
        nodes_df.filter(pl.col("node").is_in(nodes))
        .select((pl.col(("x", "y", "z"))))
        .mean()
    )

def centroid(el_id: int):
    # get the first four nodes ids for el with id = el_id
    nodes = elements_df.filter(pl.col("element") == el_id).to_numpy()[0][:4]
    return coords(nodes)

# loop over all elements and create new dataframe
# or maybe use this schema:
# _tmp = {"element": [], "x": [],"y": [],"z": []}
_tmp = {"element": [], "centroid": []}
for el in elements:
    c = centroid(el).to_numpy()[0]
    _tmp["element"].append(el)
    _tmp["centroid"].append(c)
    # _tmp["x"].append(c[0])
    # _tmp["y"].append(c[1])
    # _tmp["z"].append(c[2])

# concat dataframes to add the new "centroid" column
elements_df = pl.concat((elements_df, pl.DataFrame(_tmp)), how="align")
```

the results will be something like:

```
shape: (3, 12)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───┬─────┬─────┬──────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ element ┆ N_1 ┆ N_2 ┆ N_3 ┆ … ┆ N_8 ┆ N_9 ┆ N_10 ┆ centroid                  │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---                       │
│ i64     ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ list[f64]                 │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 8   ┆ 9   ┆ 10   ┆ [1.233333, 2.7, 2.933333] │
│ 2       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 8   ┆ 9   ┆ 10   ┆ [1.233333, 2.7, 2.933333] │
│ 3       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 8   ┆ 9   ┆ 10   ┆ [1.233333, 2.7, 2.933333] │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───┴─────┴─────┴──────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

or the commented schema:

```
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───┬──────┬──────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ element ┆ N_1 ┆ N_2 ┆ N_3 ┆ … ┆ N_10 ┆ x        ┆ y   ┆ z        │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆   ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64     ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆   ┆ i64  ┆ f64      ┆ f64 ┆ f64      │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══╪══════╪══════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 10   ┆ 1.233333 ┆ 2.7 ┆ 2.933333 │
│ 2       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 10   ┆ 1.233333 ┆ 2.7 ┆ 2.933333 │
│ 3       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 10   ┆ 1.233333 ┆ 2.7 ┆ 2.933333 │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───┴──────┴──────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

I'm sure that what I did here can be done directly in polar but I don't know where to start. This is my simplest, but I wold have to compute other things by cross referencing the both dataframes, so I want to learn how to do it. And also looking for advices on my schemas

Comment: It would be easier to help if you made the example runnable with sample input/output. It sounds like you want to use a [`join`](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/transformations/joins/) to combine frames (and possibly use [`melt`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt) to reshape `elements_df` before joining).

Comment: Two things; 1. Obligatory: please produce some sample inputs and what the desired output is given those inputs. 2. general tip: with DataFrames in general and polars especially, you don't want to be switching between python lists, dicts, etc. You want to do everything with DataFrames or else there's no benefit to them.

Comment: I update my example with a working code. @DeanMacGregor thanks for your 2nd  tips, I know it, thas why I wont to put all in DataFrame code, thinking that I can have more than 500K elements. my code was just an example, I know that I can't use it in this way

Comment: Is it a coincidence that `elements=[1,2,3]` and that the `element` column of `elements_df` is also `[1,2,3]` or should `elements` be thought of as `elements_df['element']`? Also, in `centroid` you're taking the first 4 columns which would be inclusive of `element`. That means you're only ever using the N_1, N_2, N_3 column. Do N_4+ have a purpose?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that for each of the `N_{x}` columns that their value is just `{x}`?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, `elements` and `elements_df['element']` are allways the same, I put it in that way to use my for loop in the example. For the centroir the Columns over N_4 are irelevant, but for other computations I need it, But I think (not sure) that the centroid can be de mean of all `N_{x} columns`.  In the case of the values of N_{x} its just an example, otherwise I will have a big sample dataset, but `N_{x}` can be any of the `nodes` in the nodes_df. I will update the example with a representation to clarify what is any dataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Optional Intermediate Step

I would start off with a `melt`/`join` like this:

```
(
    elements_df
    .melt('element', value_vars=['N_1', 'N_2','N_3'], value_name='node')
    .join(nodes_df, on='node')
    .group_by('element', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col('x','y','z').mean())
    .with_columns(centroid=pl.concat_list('x','y','z')).drop('x','y','z')
)
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ element ┆ centroid                  │
│ ---     ┆ ---                       │
│ i64     ┆ list[f64]                 │
╞═════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ [1.233333, 2.7, 2.933333] │
│ 2       ┆ [1.233333, 2.7, 2.933333] │
│ 3       ┆ [1.233333, 2.7, 2.933333] │
└─────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

If you want the `x`/`y`/`z` in their own columns then remove the last `.with_columns`.

If you want the `N_{x}` columns back then you have to do another join back to the original:

#### Final Answer

```
(
    elements_df
    .melt('element', value_vars=['N_1', 'N_2','N_3'], value_name='node')
    .join(nodes_df, on='node')
    .group_by('element', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col('x','y','z').mean())
    .join(elements_df, on='element')
    .select(pl.exclude('x','y','z'), pl.col('x','y','z'))
)
shape: (3, 14)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───┬──────┬──────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ element ┆ N_1 ┆ N_2 ┆ N_3 ┆ … ┆ N_10 ┆ x        ┆ y   ┆ z        │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆   ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64     ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆   ┆ i64  ┆ f64      ┆ f64 ┆ f64      │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══╪══════╪══════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 10   ┆ 1.233333 ┆ 2.7 ┆ 2.933333 │
│ 2       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 10   ┆ 1.233333 ┆ 2.7 ┆ 2.933333 │
│ 3       ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ … ┆ 10   ┆ 1.233333 ┆ 2.7 ┆ 2.933333 │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───┴──────┴──────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Note that the last `select` is only necessary to put the columns in order.

##### Alternate for fun

If you want to avoid the last join you can tweak the initial melt to include all the superfluous columns as part of the `id_vars` and then you can use other tricks to reform the melted columns at the end

```
(
    elements_df
    .melt(
        (id_vars := ['element',*(other_cols:=[f"N_{x}" for x in range(4,11)])]), 
        (value_vars := [x for x in elements_df.columns if x not in id_vars]),
        value_name='node'
        )
    .join(nodes_df, on='node')
    .group_by('element', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col('node'), pl.col(*other_cols).first(), pl.col('x','y','z').mean())
    .with_columns(pl.col('node').list.to_struct(fields=value_vars))
    .unnest('node')
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you recommend me some resource to learn Polars

Comment: stackoverflow and the [api guide](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/index.html). I don't have a structured guide other than the official one that I'm aware of though. It's just try stuff out until it works for me.